# Playing smooth streaming on a flash player

Tags: flash, playback, smooth-streaming

Is there any news about playing smooth streaming content on a flash player?

Comment: what you mean with smooth streams?!

Comment: Smooth streaming media delivered by IIS sever : http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming

Answer (score 0):

Not long ago Microsoft [announced](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/News/Online-Video-News/Two-Worlds-Collide-Smooth-Streaming-Meets-Flash-Player-86841.aspx) a SmoothStreaming plugin for the [OSMF](http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/) player. You can download it from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36057

For more information you can refer to the [Smooth Streaming plugin for OSMF Forum thread](http://forums.iis.net/p/1193755/2037281.aspx/1?Smooth%20Streaming%20plugin%20for%20OSMF%20Announcement%20amp%20Feedback)